# field user into assign to field of approval action microsoft flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, approval-process, flow

I have one field name " Approval Manager" in list, which i want to use in "Assigned To" field of approval action.

i have tried creating variable and using Approval manager email, but its not working out.

PS: it maybe or maybe not be manager of the current user from AD, so it can be any other with approval permission.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Assigned To field, click "See more" button, the Approval Manager column will be displayed.
[image]

Comment: hurrayy..it worked!